# Python: how to net two dict entries and take the net of a number and the key of the larger value?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

I have the following dictionaries which contain one entry each

```
a = {'long':10}
b = {'short':5}
```

I would like to net the two dictionaries to get

```
c = {'long': 5}
```

where the value 5 is the result of the larger number minus the smaller number, and the key is the key of the larger number.

Thank you

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: I was wondering if there was a simple way to do it without looping over the values and then determining which key has the larger value

Comment: What if one of the two dictionaries has more than one entry? What if they don't have the same number of entries?

Comment: they have the same number of entries

Comment: Ok, so what if they both have two entries? Which two should be compared?

Comment: no I apologize I misunderstood, each dictionary has one entry

Comment: I don't really understand why you're using dictionaries for this, or really what's going on at all. What's the context that makes this a problem you need to solve? And what has `itertools` got to do with any of this?

Answer (score 0):

This question may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but I'll assume you know what you are asking.  Keep in mind, the solution may not fully address your actual issue.

**Assumptions**

The code reflects these assumptions:

- There are two dicts
- Each dict is a singleton with one key-value pair
- The values are integers
- The resulting dict is also singleton
- The resulting key comes from the dict with the larger value
- The resulting value equals the larger minus the smaller values

**Code**

```
def d_net(a, b):
    """Return the net diff between two singleton dicts."""
    cmp_vals = lambda d: tuple(d.values())
    diff = lambda x: x[0] - x[1]

    d_max = max([a, b], key=cmp_vals)
    d_min = min([a, b], key=cmp_vals)

    key = list(d_max.keys())[0]
    vals = list(zip(d_max.values(), d_min.values()))[0]

    return {key: diff(vals)}
```

**Demo**

```
d_net({"long": 10}, {"short": 5})
# {'long': 5}
```

```
d_net({"long": 10}, {"short": 7})
# {'long': 3}
```

```
d_net({"long": 10}, {"short": 10})
# {'long': 0}
```

```
d_net({"long": -10}, {"short": -3})
# {'short': 7}
```